# count char in java

Tags: java, algorithm

what is wrong  in this code?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
public class char_digit {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int count=0;

        while (true){
            char t=(char) System.in.read();
            if (t=='0'){
                break;
            }
            count++;

        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}


run:
a
b
c
d
e
f
0
12
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I fixed the indentation on your code - it makes it much more readable.

Comment: also why do you import java.util.*; ? it's not used

Comment: Davit - you have asked 3 questions on this (apparent) homework assignment in the space of 1 hour.  Enough already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're counting whitespace characters as well, which are inserted when you hit the *Enter* button into the console. One quick fix is to use [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) check as follows:

```
        if (t=='0'){
            break;
        } else if (!Character.isWhitespace(t)) {
            count++;
        }
```

Depending on what you want to do, though, a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) may serve your purpose better. Using `System.in.read` directly is highly atypical, and especially if you're reading `char`, where a `Reader` is more suitable.

#### Related questions

- [Java I/O streams; what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160050/java-i-o-streams-what-are-the-differences)
- [What is the difference between a stream and a reader in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428076/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stream-and-a-reader-in-java)

Answer (score 8):

You're counting the newlines as well as the other characters. Try something like `if (t == '\n') continue;` before the current `if`.

Answer (score 2):

nothing is wrong. The carriage return also counts as a char (or 2 depending on your OS)